# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects when accessing PDF directly on Apache server

Tags: .htaccess, httpd.conf

Everything on my site works (Drupal PHP) except for accessing files that have been uploaded to the server.  They reside in /sites/default/files/.  I have removed my .htaccess file from /sites/default/files/ and when I try to access a file located in that directory, I get:

```
[Thu Jan 09 21:59:05 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

My virtual host is defined in my httpd.conf file as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/home"
<Directory "/var/www/html/home">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And above that, there is a "Directory" definition as such:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Includes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I really don't know where to go from here.  Everything else I found on stackoverflow referenced rewrites but it seems to me that I'm just trying to access the file directly, no magic, no referrals, rewrites, or what-have-you.

---

Edit:

This is the .htacess file I found in /var/www/html:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  # Do not cache dynamically generated pages.
  ExpiresByType text/html A1
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id: .htaccess,v 1.90.2.1 2008/07/08 09:33:14 goba Exp $
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is an htaccess file in *any* parent directory, those rules will get applied, and maybe even if you are directly accessing a file that is there. One thing that you can do to avoid mod_rewrite rules from getting applied in a directory is turning on mod rewrite in the directory and have no rules. So for example, simply put:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in the `/sites/default/files/` directory.

Comment: Well, for files that aren't there, I get a nice 404 page now.  However, for files that are there, same result - Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects.  What is being redirected if I'm accessing the URL directly?  There are apparently a bunch of hand-offs or somethings going on??

Comment: @harperville are there rules in htaccess files in the parent directory?

Comment: There isn't a .htaccess in the root or any parent directory in the path of <webroot>/sites/default/files/

Comment: Any other suggestions?  I can't serve any uploaded files and users are starting to be mean about it.

Comment: @harperville no idea why this is happening, unless you've got rewrite rules setup in your server/vhost config

Comment: I like the custom 404 that shows now.  No idea what to do about the 500 when accessing uploaded files. :\  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, Jon.  Boy was I mistaken.  I searched again and found a .htaccess file in /var/www/html/.  I thought my initial "find" covered everything but, well, I don't know how this was messed.  I have edited my post to include the newly found .htaccess.

Comment: Hi, Jon.  Are you available to provide insight on the .htaccess file I found?

Comment: @harperville No idea, everything looks fine. Simply turning on the rewrite engine should have prevented *all* rewriting. You may want to turn on the rewrite log temporarily to see what's really happening.